# Prompt keeps taking value in console of vscode, nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I am a beginner in NodeJs. I'm trying to do CRUD operations on a file. My goal is, when user chooses an option to create, read, update or delete, only that block will be executed. But in my code, when I run the application, the prompt "Press 1 for create, 2 for read: 1" keeps executing in a loop and never gets out of it. Where am I making the mistake, would anyone kindly point it out?

My index.js

```
//Dependencies
const http = require("http");
const { handleReqRes } = require("./helpers/handleReqRes"); 
const environment = require("./helpers/environments");
const data = require("./lib/data");
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });

// Handle create data
function createData() {
    // TODO: Implement create data logic
     data.create("test", "newFile", { mode: "Normal" }, (err) => {
     console.log(`Error was ${err}`);
    console.log(err);
 });
}

// Handle read data
function readData() {
    // TODO: Implement read data logic
    data.read("test", "newFile", (err, data) => {
    console.log(`Error was ${err}`);
     console.log(`Data was ${data}`);
 });
}

// Handle user input
function handleUserInput() {
    const choice = prompt("Press 1 for create, 2 for read: ");
    if (choice === "1") {
        createData();
    } else if (choice === "2") {
        readData();
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid input");
        handleUserInput();
    }
}

//App object - module scaffolding
const app = {};

//Create server
app.createServer = () => {
    const server = http.createServer(app.handleReqRes);
    server.listen(environment.port, () => {

        console.log(`Environment variable is ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${environment.port}`);
    });
}

app.handleReqRes = handleReqRes; 

//Start the server
app.createServer();

// Prompt user for input
handleUserInput();
```

My data.js file

```
//Dependencies
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

//Module scaffolding
const lib = {};

//Base directory of the data folder
lib.basedir = path.join(__dirname, "/../.data/");

//Write data to file
lib.create = (dir, file, data, callback) => {
    //Open file for writing
    fs.open(`${lib.basedir + dir}/${file}.json`, "wx", (err, fileDescriptor) => {
        if (!err && fileDescriptor) {
            //Convert data to string
            const stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(stringData);
            console.log(fileDescriptor);

            //Write data to file and close it
            fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, stringData, (err2) => {
                console.log(fileDescriptor);
                if (!err2) {
                    fs.close(fileDescriptor, (err3) => {
                        if (!err3) {
                            callback(false);
                        } else {
                            callback("Error closing new file");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    callback("Error writing to new file");
                }
            });
        } else {
            
            callback(err);
            // callback("There was an error, file may already exists OR: \n" + err);
        }
    });
}

//Read data from file
lib.read = (dir, file, callback) => {
    fs.readFile(`${lib.basedir + dir}/${file}.json`, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        callback(err, data);
    });
}
module.exports = lib;
```